# Accessing Azure Key Vault from an OWIN Web API

Tags: c#, azure, owin, azure-keyvault, owin-middleware

I have been searching most of the day for this and cannot find an answer.

I have a .net framework 4.7.2 web API using OWIN for authentication and startup.

I want to include processes to store my secrets in an Azure KeyVault. I have added a connected key vault service attempting to follow the MS documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/vs-key-vault-add-connected-service), but I don't have an IConfigurationBuilder in my startup, because I am using OWIN (I have an IAppBuilder instead).

So is there a way to do this from an OWIN app? Or is there another route to accessing a KeyVault (that doesn't require me to save a secret in my app) that I can use? SOme middleware that I can hook in (I have searched for this too, without success)

Answer (score 1):

So after a lot more playing about [this blog post](https://jumpforjoysoftware.com/2017/12/azure-key-vaults/) pointed me to a route to achieve what I wanted. It still requires the key to be held locally (and in my code, so not secured), but aside from this, it would appear to be viable.